# UIWebView doesn't refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift3

I have created an app that simply loads my pages into a `UIWebView` in Swift 3. The problem is that pages seem to cache and do not reload any changes. Anyone know how to clear the cache or delete the file data when the app closes in Xcode 8/Swift 3?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var MainWebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.webpage.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        MainWebView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `CachePolicy` for the `URLRequest` to ignore cached requests.
[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy)

Also, if your deployment target is iOS 8.0 and higher, try [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) instead of `UIWebView`

Edit:
Or you can just purge all `UIWebView` `URLRequest` Cache [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcache/1417802-removeallcachedresponses)

Comment: Ive never used WKwebviews, i'm new to swift. I have looked for the code to remove all docs, but it it doesn't work in swift 3. Do you have any advise where to look or help to create a WKWebView?

Comment: I found this on stack but it doesnt work because its for swift 2.              let day_url = NSURL(string: "http://www.domain.com")
let day_url_request = NSURLRequest(URL: day_url,
    cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
    timeoutInterval: 10.0)

Comment: ive added this         URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
        URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0 to the viewdidload func

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call webView.reload() function to refresh your web view ?

Comment: Could you post an example please, where would i put the reload function?